# Does django's URL Conf support mapping an argument to strings?

Tags: python, django

### The Problem

I'm unsure of the best way to phrase this, but here goes: (note some of this may not be syntactically/semantically correct, as it's not my actual code, but I needed it to help explain what I'm asking)

Say I have a model the model `Album`:

```
Class Album(models.Model):
    ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE = 1
    ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO = 2
    ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS = 3
    ALBUM_CHOICES = (
        (ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE, 'Single Record'),
        (ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO, 'Demo Album'),
        (ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS, 'Greatest Hits'),
    )
    album_type = models.IntegerField(choices=ALBUM_CHOICES)
```

And I want to have separate URLs for the various types of albums. Currently, the URL Conf is something like so:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^singles/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.AlbumView, name="singles"),
    url(r'^demos/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.AlbumView, name="demos"),
    url(r'^greatest-hits/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.AlbumView, name="greatest_hits"),
]
```

And when I want to serve the appropriate URL, I need to check the `album_type` manually:

```
if object.album_type == Album.ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE:
    return reverse('singles', object.id)
elif object.album_type == Album.ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO:
    return reverse('demos', object.id)
elif object.album_type == Album.ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS:
    return reverse('greatest_hits', object.id)
```

However, this is cumbersome to do, and I'm wondering if there is a way to pass in the `album_type` field to the call to `reverse` and have it automatically get the URL based on that. i.e. something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<type>[singles|demos|greatest-hits])/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.AlbumView, name="albums"),
]
```

and called with

```
reverse("albums", object.album_type, object.id)
```

---

### Attempted solutions

I considered setting the choice strings to be

```
ALBUM_CHOICES = (
    (ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE, 'singles'),
    (ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO, 'demos'),
    (ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS, 'greatest-hits'),
)
```

which would then allow me to send `object.get_album_type_display()` as a string variable for type, which works, however, I need to be able to use `reverse` to build the URL while only having access to the integer value of `album_type` and not the display value.

I know this is an oddly specific question for an oddly specific scenario, but if anyone has any kind of potential solutions, I'd be very grateful! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the field to a `CharField`, and use the URL slug as the actual value rather than the display value:

```
Class Album(models.Model):
    ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE = 'singles'
    ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO = 'demos'
    ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS = 'greatest-hits'
    ALBUM_CHOICES = (
        (ALBUM_TYPE_SINGLE, 'Single Record'),
        (ALBUM_TYPE_DEMO, 'Demo Album'),
        (ALBUM_TYPE_GREATEST_HITS, 'Greatest Hits'),
    )
    album_type = models.CharField(choices=ALBUM_CHOICES, max_length=50)
```

In your `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<type>singles|demos|greatest-hits)/(?P<pk>.+)/$', views.AlbumView, name="albums"),
]
```

Then you can reverse it by passing `album.album_type`:

```
reverse('albums', args=(album.album_type, album.pk))
```